# How to get svn to ignore symbolic links to folders

Tags: svn

I have a project tracked in svn.  On our server, the "index" and "log" folders are symbolic links to folders in a shared directory.  I don't want either of these in svn, and they are causing problems committing and updating:  i get an error doing "svn update" on the server:

`Expected 'log' to be a directory but found a file`

I tried setting them to be ignored, like

```
svn propset svn:ignore index .
svn propset svn:ignore log .
```

But update still breaks, and i can't commit these changes to . because i get this error:

`Expected '/ebs/www/apps/e_learning_resource/releases/20110121171004/log' to be a directory but found a file`

grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like log is already committed in SVN. Delete it (be careful to keep your local link or be ready to recreate it!), commit the deletion, and your ignore should be good from then on.

Comment: yeah, you're right:  when i try `svn delete log` i get `svn: 'log' is in the way of the resource actually under version control`.  So what i think happened was that at one point there was a physical log directory, and svn ignore was set on the *contents* of this dir, not the dir itself.  Then, later, the dir was replaced with a symlink to the shared folder, but nobody bothered tidying up svn.  So, i guess i need to move the symlink, make a new log dir, svn delete it, physically delete it, then put the symlink back and svn ignore that.  I'll do it later during a quiet usage time.  thx